# "Don't mess it up" meaning?

Tags: meaning

In the song of "Friends" by Marshmello & Anne-Marie:

> ```
> Ooh ooh, ooh ooh
> Ooh ooh, ooh ooh 
>
> You say you love me, I say you crazy
> We're nothing more than friends
> You're not my lover, more like a brother
> I known you since we were like ten, yeah
>
> Don't mess it up, talking that shit 
> Only gonna push me away, that's it
> When you say you love me, that make me crazy
> Here we go again
> ```

it says: "Don't mess it up".

What does it mean?

Comment: You should provide a modest amount of context, but generally that expression means that you should not create chaos or disorganization.  Googling that song it appears to be saying that one should not "mess up" a good friendship by attempting to turn it into a romance.

Comment: How about this: "talking that shit"

Comment: "Talking shit" should be explained several places on the Interweb.  Try the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=talking%20shit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the idiom **make a mess (out) of (something)**

> To handle something in a way that causes it to be disordered, damaged,
>   or ruined.

From your example

> "Don't mess it up"

it could read

"Don't ruin it."

Comment: How about this: "talking that shit"